# Check any files exist, in a given folder

Tags: java

I've updated my code to handle the listed scenario
1. Check for empty directory
2. Check if the file exist

What other things I should be looking out for when I'm trying to do a filewatch program?

I want to be able to create something that can cover all the possible scenario that could happen when monitoring the file such that when i deploy the code, I can quickly read the output and know what happened

```
package filemon;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * @author LAI XUEYANG
 * @version $Revision: 1.0 $
 */
public class filemon {

    /**
     * Method main.
     * 
     * @param args
     *            String[]
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Declare yesterday date with format as yyyyMMdd
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        // Calendar yesterdayCal = Calendar.getInstance();

        // Declare today date with format as yyyyMMdd
        Calendar todayCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String todayDate = dateFormat.format(todayCal.getTime());

        // Declaration of folder path
        File file = new File("D:\\TEST");

        // Declaration of file path
        Path filePath = Paths.get(file + "\\INCIF" + todayDate + ".txt");

        // yesterdayCal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        // String yesterdayDate = dateFormat.format(yesterdayCal.getTime());

        try {
            checkEmptyDirectory(file, filePath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        // checkFileExist();
    }

    /**
     * Method checkFileExist.
     * 
     * @param filePath
     *            Path
     */
    private static void checkFileExist(Path filePath) {
        if (Files.exists(filePath)) {
            System.out.println("Filename: " + filePath.toString());
            System.out.println("Exist in location!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Filename: " + filePath.toString());
            System.out.println("Does not exist in location!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method checkEmptyDirectory.
     * 
     * @param file
     *            File
     * @param filePath
     *            Path
     */
    private static void checkEmptyDirectory(File file, Path filePath) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            if (file.list().length > 0) {
                checkFileExist(filePath);
            } else {
                System.out
                        .println("Directory specified does not contain any files!");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Directory specified does not exist!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Inorder to find any files in a folder try to do like this

```
File f= new File(filePathString);
File[] listOfFiles = f.listFiles(); 

if(listOfFiles.length > 0){
//
}else{
//
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, I've used it to check if any files are inside the folder!

Comment: I am not a fan of this. I am walking the entire folder just to know if one file is in it.

Answer (score 1):

Using **java.io.File**

```
File f = new File(filePathString);
if(f.exists()) { /* do something */ }
```

In your code :

```
File f = new File(filePath);
if(f.exists()) { 
    if(f.isDirectory()){ System.out.println("it's a folder"); }
    System.out.println("File location: " +filePath.toString());
    System.out.println("File exist in location!");
    System.exit(0);

}
```

Comment: this will only check if the particular file name exist, the system will do something, it will not handle the scenario of empty directory.

Comment: @overst33r use isDirectory() to check if it's a folder or not , i edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

**import** java.io.*;
`File file = new File(Path);

if(file.exists()){.........}`

Answer (score 0):

Count the listed files using [File#list()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29):

```
File f = new File(filePathString);
int nOF = f.list().length; //add null check before
```

> Returns an array of strings naming the files and directories in the
>   directory denoted by this abstract pathname. If this abstract pathname
>   does not denote a directory, then this method returns null. Otherwise
>   an array of strings is returned, one for each file or directory in the
>   directory. Names denoting the directory itself and the directory's
>   parent directory are not included in the result. Each string is a file
>   name rather than a complete path.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-check-if-directory-is-empty-in-java/

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{   

File file = new File("\myFolder");

if(file.isDirectory()){

    if(file.list().length>0){

        System.out.println("Directory is not empty!");

    }else{

        System.out.println("Directory is empty!");

    }

}else{

    System.out.println("This is not a directory");

}
}
```

Comment: Yep this is the same answer provided by karthick!

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
"C:\\TEST" +todayDate +".txt"
```

You missed a folder separator. It should probably be:

```
"C:\\TEST\\" +todayDate +".txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this might will help you for check that in folder there is a file exist or not!

```
    File folder = new File("/home/rahul/Documents/r/212/");
    f.listFilesForFolder(folder);

    }
public void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
        } else {

            l.add(fileEntry.getName());
        }
    }
```

My code is getting name of all files available from directory if file exist in folder.