# Java, know if a file is inside a folder

Tags: java, file

Hi guys I'm trying to find if a specific file is inside the project directory.

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
System.out.println(f);
String archivoLiga="LigaV2";
System.out.println(f.listFiles((dir1, name) -> name.startsWith(archivoLiga) && name.endsWith(".properties")).length == 0);
```

But this only works if the file is in the "first" level, i want it to find it even if it's inside another folder. Any ideas?

Comment: See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html).

Comment: possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18823496/check-any-files-exist-in-a-given-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Java 8's `find()` method to recurse subdirectories:

```
final int MAX_DEPTH = 50;  // Max depth of subdirectories to search
Path userDir = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
System.out.println(userDir);
String archivoLiga="LigaV2";
System.out.println(
        Files.find(
                userDir,
                maxDepth,
                (path,attr) -> path.getFileName().startsWith(archivoLiga)
                        && path.getFileName().endsWith(".properties"))
        .findAny()
        .isPresent());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try recursively looking inside subfolders :-

```
public boolean checkForFile(String dirname,String prefix,String ext){

        File dir = new File(dirname);
        //System.out.println(dir);



        for(File f : dir.listFiles()){

            if(f.isFile()){
                if(f.getName().startsWith(prefix) && f.getName().endsWith(ext)){
                    System.out.println(f.getName());
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else{

                //This step starts looking inside subfolder as well 
                return checkForFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),prefix,ext);
            }

        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To check a file inside a folder, You will need to use `exists()` method of `java.io.File` like this:

```
boolean exists = new File("FOLDER_PATH/FILE_NAME").exists();

if (exists) {
    System.out.println("File exists inside given folder");
} else {
    System.out.println("File does not exists inside given folder");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also possible with `FileVisitor`:

```
@Getter @Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public static class SearchVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {
    private final String fileToSearch;
    private boolean found=false;

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        if(!file.getFileName().toString().equals(fileToSearch)) return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        found=true;
        return FileVisitResult.TERMINATE;
    }
}

public void test() throws IOException {
    SearchVisitor sv = new SearchVisitor("LigaV2");
    Files.walkFileTree( Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir")), sv);
    log.info("found file {}:{}", sv.getFileToSearch(), sv.isFound());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `public boolean isDirectory()` in java file API following is the link to oracle documentation. Tests whether the file denoted by this abstract pathname is a directory.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()